# SSIS Loading from Excel Problem

Tags: excel, ssis

I've written an SSIS package which reads all the worksheets from an Excel workbook into a database.

It's mostly working. It reads all the worksheets in a loop from the workbook.

The only downside is that it's reading **sheetname** and then **sheetname$**, so is duplicating lots of the data. I'm quite new to SSIS, so not sure how I could filter this using my Foreach loop (or something within it).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the sheet name in a variable you may be able to test the value of the variable in a Precedence Constraint (line between tasks).  In your Foreach container, right-click on the line and select Edit...  This will display the Precedence Constraint Editor.

In the editor, select Expression and Constraint in the Evaluation Operation input.  Leave the Value as Success to indicate that the previous task must succeed before the next task will run.  Add a test to the Expression box that, when true, will let the next task run.  The expression can test for the sheet names that you want to process.  For all others flow will not continue to the next task, and the current Foreach iteration will complete.

Comment: Thanks very much. Once I got the FINDSTRING the right way around this solved the problem beautifully.